# Get number of followers for specific page in Mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, schema

let's say I have a collection called pages as

```json
{
  _id: "pageid",
  name: "Mongodb"
},
{
  _id: "pageid2",
  name: "Nodejs"
}
```

and user collection as follows

```json
{
  _id : "userid1",
  following: ["pageid"],
  ...
},
{
  _id : "userid2",
  following: ["pageid", "pageid2"],
  ...
}
```

how could I make a query to retrieve the pages information along with the number of users follow each page in mongodb, expected result as follows

```json
[
  {
    _id: "pageid",
    name: "MongoDB",
    followers: 2
  },
  {
    _id: "pageid2",
    name: "Nodejs",
    followers: 1
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$lookup` and `$size` to count total followers,

```
db.pages.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "user",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "following",
      as: "followers"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      followers: { $size: "$followers" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/16hKJUaxqez)

Comment: does that pull only `following` field from `users` collection? ( I am new to MongoDB)

Comment: yes, you can compare and experiment the followers count.